# How do you design a text-based view using Ember.js or some other MVC javascript framework?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an homemade javascript which, among other things, do some kind of text-formatting work in order to emulate a retro text-based game:

When developing it, i tried to stick close to an MVC model, and this is what i did:

The data model basically consists of a list of objects mapping strings to very specific locations in the display, like this

```
[{
 "value":"Hello!",
 "color":"blue",
 "row":1,
 "column":13
},
{
 "value":"What is your quest ?",
 "color":"red",
 "row":5,
 "column":10
},

/* ... some other data */]
```

Then my view consists of a simple `<pre>` tag. When my controller draws the model on the view, it iterates through each string-location pair and create a `<span>` for each one that is appended to the `<pre>` tag. To keep the formatting consistent, it also adds "blanck" span each time it is needed.

```
<pre>
  <span>             </span><span class="blue">Hello!</span><span>          </span><br>
  <!-- ... other lines of the scene-->
</pre>
```

It's pretty simple, but it worked great until i had to dynamically change a span text value, without redrawing the whole scene each time.

So i took a look on the internet and realized that Ember.js existed, it really seems to be exactly what i could use to improve my whole code.

Now, i tried to redesign it using Ember.js, but as i don't fully understand yet its features i ran into a problem:

**How do you represent a 'text-based' view into an Ember.js handlebar template ?**

What am i missing here?
My data model contains both the *value* **and** the *position in the display*, so i don't exactly see how handlebars template could fit my needs. Or perhaps dynamically generating the template is an option ?

What do you think ?
Am I choosing the wrong framework or misunderstanding its use? is it my original MVC design that is wrong ? Changing the data model for something completely different is not an option i can easily consider as it would impact everything.

Do you have any ideas on how this could be implemented using Ember or some other framework?

Any advice will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a rudimentary example on jsfiddle on how you could use ember for this.

Each row is an object and we have an `ArrayProxy` holding such objects. Thus if we have 10 rows, we have 10 row objects.

The view is binding one output line per row object.

Enjoy the flying bird:

http://jsfiddle.net/algesten/YMrW3/2/

Edit: Better to {{#if}} away empty rows as pointed out by ud3323:

http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/92b24/

Comment: Nice solution Martin. The only two things I'd change is adding an if statement to the handlebars so extra views aren't getting rendered (takes number of Metamorph views created down by 10) and using `beginPropertyChanges()` and `endPropertyChanges()` since you're setting multiple properties on an object at once. See my [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/92b24/).

Comment: This is a great solution. I really appreciate your help here. Your solution and the update will enable me to go further with this framework, which, i must say, do really seem to makes things easy.

Comment: nice bird too btw ^^ just had one problem with IE<9 where the bird continued flying through the whole screen and further. This seem related to the space character, cause replacing it by '&nbsp;' fixed it. Any idea what could cause that ?